# How to modify the SNP values?

Tags: sas, genetics

My dataset has 3 SNPs which looks like below

```
Id  SNP1 SNP 2 SNP3  
1    AA   AA    AA  
2    AG   AC    AG  
3    GG   CC    GG  
4    
5
6  So on
```

In SNP1 - I would like to modify the values AA =2, AG =1, GG = 0 and Likewise in SNP1 and SNP2

How can I do this?

Comment: Why not use a simple if statement in a datastep `if SNP1="AA" then SNP1 = "2"; if SNP1="AG" then SNP1="1";...`? How many different replacement values can snp have, only the 3 you mentioned? If so, i would go the simple if way, otherwise if you have many different values which should be replaced, i would build a macro with a do loop to automatize it...

Answer (score 0):

I would put the new values in a `proc format`, so that you can either keep the existing values but displayed with the formatted value, or convert the existing values using the format.  Here are both ways to do this.

```
/* create format */
proc format;
    value $snpfmt   'AA'    =   '2'
                    'AG'    =   '1'
                    'GG'    =   '0'
;
run;

/* create initial dataset */
data have;
input Id SNP1 $ SNP2 $ SNP3 $;
datalines;
1   AA  AA  AA
2   AG  AC  AG
3   GG  CC  GG
;

/* option1 - format the values */
proc datasets lib=work nodetails nolist;
modify have;
format snp1 snp2 snp3 $snpfmt2. ;
quit;

/* option2 - change the values using the format */
data want;
set have;
snp1 = put(snp1,$snpfmt2.);
snp2 = put(snp2,$snpfmt2.);
snp3 = put(snp3,$snpfmt2.);
run;
```

Comment: Thank you very much! Let me try this!